# moving a picture fluently over a winform

Tags: c#, timer

I've added a timer control to a winform (just by drag and drop using VS2017).
This timer control moves a picture from left to right on the form. When its enabled.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int x = PictureBox1.Location.X + 1;

    if (x < 400) 
        PixtureBox1.Location = new Point(x, 100);
}
```

The problem is that this move operation is moving not fluently, its moving shaky. I have to stick to winform, and wonder what can be done about this shaky movement?

If tried to minimize the interval or increasing the displacement but it keeps shaky.

Comment: what interval are you using?

Comment: The is no fluent animation in Winforms as it can't synch with the monitor refresh. For some cases you also may want to do the tracking in floats but your example only goes per 1 pixel anyway.. - Note the difference between shakiness and flicker; the latter can be avoide by double-buffering.

Comment: indeed it seams a bit hard to do on Winforms, currently with a low time intervall its relatively smooth, maybe it could be better with some proper thread delay (not sure), or dynamic movement on ticks time.. i'm not sure was hoping to find a solution there but all optimizations so far in that direction dont improve it a lot. A solution might not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have to try using the `OnPaint()` method to do your animations. Here is a link to the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint).
You can have a timer which is set to fire for a target **framerate** you want to achieve and call `InvalidateRect()` or `Invalidate(true)` to redraw the entire window.

By frame rate I mean the number of times the control you are animating has to be redrawn, if you want a frame rate of 30, calculate the timer interval by `1000/30` as 1000 ms = 1 second.

Thus `timer.Interval = 1000/30` and In the **timer.Tick** event call the `Invalidate()` to trigger the **OnPaint**() event.

Comment: Could you clarify it a bit more, been reading the article but no reference to framerate, and not clear to me how the timer event could be changed with onpaint

Comment: @user3800527 Edited my answer to include some explanation.